# Good measures to quantify the effect of outliers

Tags: random-variable, outliers, scatterplot

I have two random quantities linked to a set of N random variables. Increasing N The two random quantities should gradually become similar (meaning that the 2 distributions narrows around the same value). If I collect more sets of data and compute the 2 quantity for each set I can perform a scatter plot of the 2 variables.
Increasing N in each set and repeating the scatter plot with the new group of set I see that the scatter plot narrows over the bisector (as expected for what I said above)
Now I want to quantify this:
What are standard methods to better quantify this narrowing?
I have a group of point distant from the bisector that naturally arise for finite N, but whose impact reduces increasing N. How can I quantify the reduction of this outliers in the "distriution" of distances from the bisector line?